# Mysql query or code for time range search

Tags: php, mysql

Is there anybody who write query for time range. I am searching from last 6 days when I get the result it will all about dates. Where are times?

I need a solution for searching e.g. from 12:00:00 PM to 04:00:00 PM in datetime field. So how can I search that from mysql table on whatever dates the have. But the result will how on that time range. Any body have solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TIME() function, it extract the time portion from a datetime field  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time

```
SELECT TIME(datetime_col) FROM table
WHERE TIME(datetime_col) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '16:00:00'
```